# What is the meaning of initializing weights from a distribution function

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, neural-networks

I'm a machine learning newbie. I was going through various initializers that come with TFLearn, and it says that the "weights are picked up randomly from some probability distribution function"

**What I interpreted:**

If let's say we are using **normal distribution** function **centered at** some value **'x'** and has **std.deviation = 'y'** for weight initialization of network.

Then does that mean, that most of the weights in my neural network nodes will be initialized to 'x' (since normal function at 'x' is highest and hence 'x' has the highest probability of occurrence) and the probability of other values being assigned to the weights will gradually decrease (as per the std.deviation 'y') as I move to either sides of 'x' ?

Is my interpretation correct ?

Comment: In general, if you sample from any continuous distribution function, including the normal distribution, the probability at hitting some fixed value $x$ will always be 0.

Comment: @shimao I don't understand. Can you please elaborate

Comment: Yes. In every (nondegenerate) continuous distribution, there is an uncountably infinite set of values which can be sampled from that distribution. Intuitively, if you try to assign a positive probability to each possible value, your probabilities will sum to infinity, which isn't allowed.

Comment: Strictly speaking the probability is exactly 0, not infinitesimal. Keep in mind that probability 0 doesn't mean that it can't occur. But your general intuition is correct that if a normal distribution is centered on $\mu$, you will see most of the samples pretty close to $\mu$ and the farther out you get the fewer samples you'll see.

Comment: ok, now i understand what you meant to say. so i can't assign any positive value of probability to any particular value and each value has an infinitesimally small probability of occurrence (as good as zero) . But then what does sampling from a probability distribution mean ? does it mean that (for normal distribution) most of the initialized weights will be centered around 'x' and how far the values deviate from the 'x' is governed by the std. deviation ?

Comment: oh, sorry i was editing my comment when your answer came .

Comment: Generally for continuous distributions you'll have a probability density function $f(x)$, which specifies if you sample from the distribution, the probability of ending up with a value between $a$ and $b$ is $\int_a^b f(x) dx$. So any procedure which can draw numbers while adhering to this specification would be a valid sampling method.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I understand it now. Would you mind putting this in form of an answer rather than a comment, so that i can mark this question as "answered", for benefit of others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer by shimao :

In every (nondegenerate) continuous distribution, there is an uncountably infinite set of values which can be sampled from that distribution. Intuitively, if you try to assign a positive probability to each possible value, your probabilities will sum to infinity, which isn't allowed.

Strictly speaking the probability is exactly 0, not infinitesimal. Keep in mind that probability 0 doesn't mean that it can't occur. But your general intuition is correct that if a normal distribution is centered on μ, you will see most of the samples pretty close to μ and the farther out you get the fewer samples you'll see.

Generally for continuous distributions you'll have a probability density function f(x), which specifies if you sample from the distribution, the probability of ending up with a value between a and b is integration-from-a-to-b(f(x)dx). So any procedure which can draw numbers while adhering to this specification would be a valid sampling method.